# How to parse worldtide.info JSON with two low/high tides per cycle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, geography

Hi everyone I am back again, this is my second question. This time I wish to get tidal prediction data from worldtide.info to work and output as HTML. The problem is that each cycle has two low, and two high tides with the same sort of reference, I think. I am a noobie.  Is it some '.' misplaced or something to do with the JSON structure? Feel free to shorten the code. Thank you for reading. Below is the code, that do not output, as is and a JSFiddle:

## JSON

```
{

    "status":200,
    "callCount":1,
    "requestLat":"-9",
    "requestLon":"147",
    "responseLat":-9.099998,
    "responseLon":146.9,
    "atlas":"TPXO_8_v1",
    "copyright":"Tidal data retrieved from www.worldtide.info. Copyright © 2014-2017 FaMe IT. Licensed for use of individual spatial coordinates on behalf of/by an end-user. Copyright © 2010-2016 Oregon State University. Licensed for individual spatial coordinates via ModEM-Geophysics Inc. NO GUARANTEES ARE MADE ABOUT THE CORRECTNESS OF THIS DATA. You may not use it if anyone or anything could come to harm as a result of using it (e.g. for navigational purposes).",
    "extremes":[
    {
    "dt":1489824260,
    "date":"2017-03-18T08:04+0000",
    "height":-0.191,
    "type":"Low"
    },
    {
    "dt":1489866721,
    "date":"2017-03-18T19:52+0000",
    "height":0.272,
    "type":"High"
    },
    {
    "dt":1489896470,
    "date":"2017-03-19T04:07+0000",
    "height":-0.141,
    "type":"Low"
    },
    {
    "dt":1489908798,
    "date":"2017-03-19T07:33+0000",
    "height":-0.104,
    "type":"High"
    },
    {
    "dt":1489926121,
    "date":"2017-03-19T12:22+0000",
    "height":-0.208,
    "type":"Low"
    },
    {
    "dt":1489953836,
    "date":"2017-03-19T20:03+0000",
    "height":0.415,
    "type":"High"
    },
    {
    "dt":1489979503,
    "date":"2017-03-20T03:11+0000",
    "height":-0.218,
    "type":"Low"
    }
    ]
    }
```

#### JAVASCRIPT

```
$.getJSON("https://www.worldtides.info/api?extremes&lat=-9&lon=147&key=<API KEY HERE>", function(data) {
console.log(data);

//setting up the variables
var tide1 = data.extremes.[0].height
var tide2 = data.extremes.[1].height
var tide3 = data.extremes.[2].height
var tide4 = data.extremes.[3].height

var time1 = data.extremes.[0].time
var time2 = data.extremes.[1].time
var time3 = data.extremes.[2].time
var time4 = data.extremes.[3].time

var type1 = data.extremes.[0].type
var type2 = data.extremes.[1].type
var type3 = data.extremes.[2].type
var type4 = data.extremes.[3].type

// to insert in table
    $('#tide1').text(tide1)
    $('#tide2').text(tide2)
    $('#tide3').text(tide3)
    $('#tide4').text(tide4)

    $('#time1').text(time1)
    $('#time2').text(time2)
    $('#time3').text(time2)
    $('#time4').text(time3)

    $('#type1').text(type1)
    $('#type2').text(type2)
    $('#type3').text(type3)
    $('#type4').text(type4)     

});
```

#### HTML

```
<tt>
<h3>TIDAL TIMES</h3>
<table border="1" width=150 class="extremes">
<tr><td id="tide1"></td><td id="time1"></td><td id="type1"></td></tr>
<tr><td id="tide2"></td><td id="time2"></td><td id="type2"></td></tr>
<tr><td id="tide3"></td><td id="time3"></td><td id="type3"></td></tr>
<tr><td id="tide4"></td><td id="time4"></td><td id="type4"></td></tr>
</table>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kmg747/0yg3970m/3/)

Comment: Do you want to get from this json response an object with lowest and highest tide value i.e. `{ minTide: xxx, maxTide: yyyy }`?

Comment: Oh hi there.. @loretoparisi I think so, want simple text output of the two low and high plus the the times of them. Please provide complete code I am new to this and just a line of code for me is cryptic. The date would be nice too. Thank you.

Comment: Try the response below it should be fine (only javascript, you then have to fulfill your HTML via JQuery.

Comment: @loretoparisi or just TODAY/TOMOROOW, you got my head spinning a little. :)

Comment: @loretoparisi Thanks again. Just run your code and it seems to really be going places, though the output looks as a new array to me, and that confuses me. Wish to get the HTML output of a set of two high and low and tides per 24 hours. Though just checked and it has **4 Low and 3 High in the JSON!** . So wish to know about the future tides as in that JSON URL, high and low, Sorry about this.

Comment: @loretoparisi studying your code now. I am very new at this so find it hard to understand snippets without seeing all the pieces.

Comment: Well you may want to learn about modern javascript, so I'm using there array `filter`, the `arrow` operator, a classic array `sort` with function to operate on array of objects. The sorting function shows all the pieces i.e. it would be very simpler that that. I will add some doc reference wait a minute...

Comment: @loretoparisi Guess I can add, c, d, e, f, g somehow?

Comment: please define c, d, e, f and g variables / values.

Comment: @loretoparisi Just thought that c, d, e, f.. could perhaps be the upcoming future lows and highs tides, though probably not since they might have been filtered away?  Basically just wish to have the lows and high from the next plus the times and date as just plain 'TT', or teletype text in simple table. And if talking future, labeled TODAY or TONIGHT, TOMORROW, and then with MON-SUN or WED-FRI. But now I am spinning off, At the moment I just want the simplest solution. I am so so happy that you assist. Wish we could chat, I do not have enough points apparently.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood well, and you want a fast way to get highest/lowest tide value you do as simple as

```
var lowestTide=res.extremes.filter(tide => { return tide.type=="Low"; }).sort(function(a,b) {return (a.height > b.height) ? -1 : ((b.height > a.height) ? 1 : 0);} )[0]

var highestTide=res.extremes.filter(tide => { return tide.type=="High"; }).sort(function(a,b) {return (a.height > b.height) ? -1 : ((b.height > a.height) ? 1 : 0);} )[0]
```

```js
$.getJSON("https://www.worldtides.info/api?extremes&lat=-9&lon=147&key=863f3f3f-2ce7-40bb-912b-f6a8d862aedd", function(data) {


  var lowestTide = data.extremes.filter(tide => {
    return tide.type == "Low";
  }).sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a.height > b.height) ? -1 : ((b.height > a.height) ? 1 : 0);
  })[0];

  var highestTide = data.extremes.filter(tide => {
    return tide.type == "High";
  }).sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a.height > b.height) ? -1 : ((b.height > a.height) ? 1 : 0);
  })[0];


  console.log("LOWEST TIDE:", lowestTide, "HIGHEST TIDE", highestTide);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Description:**

I have used [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function to filter out values by `type` field (in turn type='High' and type='Low'), then a [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) sorting function to sort the objects array in descending order.

Comment: Not the solution I am looking for perhaps.  Lost in the code. Think my JSfiddle was unsaved earlier now it is saved. Assistare mi prego, mi scusi mio codice sono, Che pizza!.